# How to have hidden link actions on PNG image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, png

http://www.ika-world.com/search.php?view=weltkarte

See link for example.
Image is a PHP created PNG image. When viewing just the image, then no link actions are present.
I cant figure out how the link actions are added. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no imagemap on the page,  I believe that the page is using javascript to set up a click listener.  It then gets the X/Y position of the click and changes the URL with the new parameters.  The javascript is compacted so i cannot tell you exactly how to replicate it, but that is how he is doing it.

Comment: I did decompact both javascript files using simply replaces.
Found http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/ helpful, but was still unable to follow the steps through the code.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with [image maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.6).